# How to use source() in a .Rmd file when accessing code from multiple folders?

Tags: r, file-structure

I've started to explore calling and reusing code snippets in various .Rmd projects. I'm running into issues though with the working directory not being able to access the correct files.

Take this file structure, for instance:

```
R/
├─ code/
│  ├─ compile_data.R
├─ my_functions/
│  ├─ function_01.R
├─ report/
│  ├─ report.Rmd
```

When running the `report.Rmd` file I have an option to recompile the underlying data with `compile_data.R` as such:

```
recompile <- TRUE

if (recompile == TRUE) {
  source("../code/compile_data.R")
}
```

This call works as expected, but fails when `compile_data.R` script tries to call a custom function via

```
source('R/my_functionfunctions/function_01.R')
```

I'm assuming I need to change my working directory somewhere but not sure where to do it so that I can access the `code` files from anywhere without breaking the sub-calls to other scripts.

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: And is the path `R/my_functionfunctions/function_01.R` just a typo in the question? That's not going to work...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think it's good advice:  don't do that.  Put your code in one or more packages, and use those packages from your document.  It is really easy to create an R package, and it solves the kind of problems that you are facing, as well as many others.

Comment: try source('../my_functions/function_01.R')

Comment: What do you mean by .Rmd projects? Have you created an rstudio project? If so, how is your `R Markdown` Evaluate chunks in option set in rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of these types of errors, besides making a package as some of the comments recommended is to use a package called [here](https://here.r-lib.org). In practice it would look like this:

report.rmd

```
recompile <- TRUE

if (recompile == TRUE) {
  source(here("code/compile_data.R"))
}
```

compile_data.R

```
source(here('my_functions/function_01.R'))
```

Bonus because you no longer need to `setwd()`.

Why I like here:
When you have a complicated project with multiple folders where your scripts are, worrying about the working directory gets complicated. Being able to reference everything from your project directory helps make your code more readable (no paths like `../../main_folder/random_script.R`) and more portable (because you get rid of paths like `~/directory/stuct/specific_to_computer`). I think these benefits outweigh the addition of a dependency.

Bonus 2: you can also build a path like this `here("directory", "dir2", "file.R")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `rmd` file should compile from your working directory, `R/`.

When you source from `code`, everything should run without path problems. Edit the line in `compile_data.R` to `source('../my_functions/function_01.R')` instead.

In case you need to switch to a different directory during knitting, you can use a custom function like the one below:

```r
# taken from adv-r 1st ed http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#return-values
in_dir <- function(dir, code) {
  old = setwd(dir)
  on.exit(setwd(old))
  force(code)
}
```

````
```{r}
recompile = TRUE

if (recompile) {
  in_dir("code/", source("compile_data.R"))
}
```
````